# does acf_save_post cause endless loop?

Tags: functions, save-post, advanced-custom-fields

I am using Advanced custom fields `acf_save_post` hook in one of my functions. In that function I use the `add_post_meta` function. Does this call `acf_save_post` again and cause an endless loop?

http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/docs/functions/hooks-filters/#acf_save_post

Comment: How about posting a link to the plugin you're talking about? Also please look at the WYSIWG editor and try to find the "code format" button. Thanks.

Comment: This would be better suited for the ACF forums - Elliot (the main dev) can probably help you quicker than someone unfamiliar with the intricacies of the plugin.

Comment: Thanks, I will ask Elliot. Just checking to see if it was possible because my database is crashing a lot more than it should, so I feel there is a loop somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`add_post_meta` doesn't call the same hook again but there are some other functions such as `wp_update_post` which call the hook again. In case it is going into infinite loop you'll have to call `remove_action` inside the function to not make it recursive